# Using JQ (or any other .json tool), how can I update an object within an array and return the entire parent .json?

Tags: node.js, json, command-line, jq

For example, say I have the following .json blob:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1234567890,
    "report": "Age Report",
    "results": [
        { "name": "John", "age": 43, "city": "TownA" },
        { "name": "Jane",  "age": 10, "city": "TownB" }
    ]
}
```

I want to change John's age to 44, and then return the entire blob. I'm looking for the following output:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1234567890,
    "report": "Age Report",
    "results": [
        { "name": "John", "age": 44, "city": "TownA" },
        { "name": "Joe",  "age": 10, "city": "TownB" }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, if "age" is not there, I would like to add it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way using [`map`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example21) and [`if-then-else`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else):

```
.results |= map(if .name == "John" then .age = 44 else . end)
```

<sup>[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CSC6IoLfD8)</sup>

---

Another using [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example28):

```
( .results[] | select(.name == "John") | .age) |= 44
```

<sup>[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1R1vV3Zquy)</sup>

---

Both versions rely on:

- `|=`:  [Update-assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=)

---

---

> Additionally, if "age" is not there, I would like to add it.

This requires an additional filter, something like

```
( .results[] | select(.age | not )) += { "age": 1 }
```

Were we use [`not`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example76) to [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example28) all the objects without `.age` and then add it.

Combining both filters, would give something like:

```
( .results[] | select(.age | not )) += { "age": 1 } | ( .results[] | select(.name == "John") | .age) |= 44
```

<sup>[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Q8C4kQu_Tg)</sup>

Comment: Re "*`( .results[] | select(.age | not )) += { "age": 1 }`*", [`.results[].age //= 1`](https://jqplay.org/s/CHynajJqzI) would be sufficient. I think the OP only meant John's age, though. Your first two snippets already handle that.

Answer (score 0):

As setting an object's field to a value given does not require its previous content (or its existence even), there is no need for the update operator `|=`. A simple assignment `=` does suffice to set (or create) a certain field.

```
(.results[] | select(.name == "John")).age = 44
```

This [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/v4DuIMKLRG) contains the input twice, once as given and once with John's `.age` missing.